# Why acetaldehyde and acetone have almost equal water solubility?

Tags: hydrogen-bond

Given that boiling point of acetaldehyde and acetone are different due to H-bonding, why doesn't H-bond affect the solubility of these compounds in water?

Comment: They are both completely miscible with water.